# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'predict'

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

I know there are a lot of similar questions like mine but no luck trying their solutions so far.

`dlnet` is a class with a function `gd(self, X, Y, iter = 3000)`, which essentially equals to `train()`

```
def gd(self,X, Y, iter = 3000):
    np.random.seed(1)                         

    self.nInit()

    for i in range(0, iter):
        Yh, loss=self.forward()
        self.backward()

    return
```

I tried to use `predict()` on the trained model but it gave me:

> 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'predict'

```
nn = dlnet(x_train,y_train)
nn.gd(x_train, y_train, iter = 15000)
Y_train_predict=nn.predict(x_train)
Y_test_predict=nn.predict(x_test)
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: So ```nn``` is None. I would print the value of nn after the first and second line to narrow down the problem.

Comment: Are you certain that you didn't accidentally do something like `nn = nn.gd(x_train, y_train, iter = 15000)`?

Comment: @EricTruett correct me if I'm wrong, nn is a trained model after the second line

Comment: @dspencer I did not assign the trained model to anything and tried to predict() it but didn't work

Comment: @stlchz Please provide the traceback for the error to show which of your `predict` calls raises this error. You likely also need to provide further code from your `dlnet` class, including `predict`.

Comment: My wild guess is that your gd method needs to `return self`.

Comment: OP is referencing functions and classes that are not standard ones. I recommend him to post the whole code along with the traceback so we can better understand the problem....